# Filter space html tag &nbsp;

Tags: php

I want to filter the variable with the following `php` codes.

```
if(empty($cell) || $cell =='&nbsp;')
{
    $cell = "<input type ='text'></input>";
}
```

I know for sure the `$cell` equal to `&nbsp;` only but I don't understand why I don't get `input texts field` as the output.

Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: Have you `print_r($cell);` to make sure of what you're dealing with and what is the data ? perhaps you're converting it back to a space or there are spaces around it.

Comment: Fix your HTML first, then examine again.

Comment: @Wrikken I agree that his HTML is broken but if his condition is right it should show a text box regarless

Comment: adding `echo $cell` ???

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed it. It was some other codes that affect the condition.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to echo $cell inside your condition. :)